# What's better readSync or createReadStream (with Symbol.asyncIterator)?

Tags: node.js, fs

1. createReadStream (with Symbol.asyncIterator)

```
async function* readChunkIter(chunksAsync) {
  for await (const chunk of chunksAsync) {
    // magic
    yield chunk;
  }
}

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { highWaterMark: 1024 * 64 });
const readChunk = readChunkIter(fileStream);
```

2. readSync

```
function* readChunkIter(fd) {
  // loop
    // magic
    fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, chunkSize, bytesRead);
    yield buffer;
}

const fd = fs.openSync(filePath, 'r');
const readChunk = readChunkIter(fd);
```

What's better to use with a generator function and why?

**upd:** I'm not looking for a better way, I want to know the difference between using these features

Comment: Depends entirely on usecase.  Some will say it's better to always be async, but if your program can't continue until a critical file is loaded, why bother with the overhead?  In your example, they are both effectively running in a synchronous manner.

Comment: As you will learn here on stackoverflow, ***which is better*** is entirely opinion until you offer some objective criteria for how better is judged and questions calling primarily for opinion are discouraged here (and often downvoted, though I didn't downvote you since you're new here).  I've offered comments on your general two approaches in my answer below (attempting to avoid the opinion side of things as best as possible).

Comment: @jfriend00, Thank you for the answer. I really didn't ask the right question. I'm not looking for a better way, I want to know the difference between using these features.

Comment: I added a note about that to my answer below.  On stackoverflow, if you realize that you aren't communicating the proper question, you can use the "edit" link below the question to clarify your question (in the question, not just in comments).  This should be to clarify your original question, not to change it into an entirely different question (as that is unfair to people that have already provided answers to what you original asked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you're comparing a synchronous file operation `fs.readSync()` with an asynchronous one in the stream (which uses `fs.read()` internally).  so, that's a bit like apples and oranges for server use.

If this is on a server, then NEVER use synchronous file I/O except at server startup time because when processing requests or any other server events, synchronous file I/O blocks the entire event loop during the file read operation which drastically reduces your server scalability.  Only use asynchronous file I/O, which between your two cases would be the stream.

Otherwise, if this is not on a server or any process that cares about blocking the node.js event loop during a synchronous file operation, then it's entirely up to you on which interface you prefer.

---

Other comments:

1. It's also unclear why you wrap `for await()` in a generator.  The caller can just use `for await()` themselves and avoid the wrapping in a generator.
2. Streams for reading files are usually used in an event driven manner by adding an event listener to the `data` event and responding to data as it arrives.  If you're just going to asynchronously read chunks of data from the file, there's really no benefit to a stream.  You may as well just use `fs.read()` or `fs.promises.read()`.
3. We can't really comment on the best/better way to solve a problem without seeing the overall problem you're trying to code for.  You've just shown one little snippet of reading data. The best way to structure that depends upon how the higher level code can most conveniently use/consume the data (which you don't show).

> I really didn't ask the right question. I'm not looking for a better way, I want to know the difference between using these features.

Well, the main difference is that `fs.readSync()` is blocking and synchronous and thus blocks the event loop, ruining the scalability of a server and should never be used (except during startup code) in a server environment.  Streams in node.js are asynchronous and do not block the event loop.

Other than that difference, streams are a higher level construct than just reading the file directly and should be used when you're actually using features of the streams and should probably not be used when you're just reading chunks from the file directly and aren't using any features of streams.

In particular, error handling is not always so clear with streams, particularly when trying to use `await` and promises with streams.  This is probably because readstreams were originally designed to be an event driven object and that means communicating errors indirectly on an `error` event which complicates the error handling on straight read operations.  If you're not using the event driven nature of readstreams or some transform feature or some other major feature of streams, I wouldn't use them - I'd use the more traditional `fs.promises.readFile()` to just read data.